# Copy a range from a number of workbooks without opening a file

Tags: vba, excel, loops, import

My code is:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Wiersz = 102
For i = 1 To Wiersz
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Katalog & "U" & i & ".xlsx", ReadOnly:=True


    Range("D11:D210").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E1:E200").Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


    Workbooks("U" & i & ".xlsx").Close
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Where Katalog is a given file path. All files are named U1.xlsx, ...,U102.xlsx
I want to copy identical range from each of those file. However the mechanism above is extremely slow because for 102 files it takes 47 seconds. I want this to work on e.g. 1000 files thus i am looking for a method to speed up my macro.

What should i change to do that? Preferably i would be satisfied with the execution time of this code below 10 seconds. Is there any possibility to read a closed file or maybe somehow use VBA arrays for that?

In general i am looking for a fast algorithm to deal with huge number of xlsx files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bit of code (borrowed from http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=155964:

```
Sub GetRange() 
    With Range("A2:A20") 
        .Formula = "='C:\[Test.xlsx]Test'!D2:D20" 
        .Value = .Value 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Gives a notion of how you can pull a range from a closed file. I think this method could be adapted to work for you.

Here is an implementation that MIGHT work for you.

```
Sub GetRangesFromClosedWorkbooks()
    Dim Source As String
    Dim Wiersz As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Wiersz = 102
    For i = 1 To Wiersz
        Source = "='C:\sql\[KatalogU" & i & ".xlsx]'!D1:D210"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E1:E210").Offset(0, i).Select
        With Selection
            .Formula = Source
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hopefully someone might show us a way to do this without using the Select as I'm sure it could go faster without that.

Comment: try `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obliczenia").Range("E1:E210").Offset(0, i)` , then following lines `.Formula = Source` and `.Value = .Value`

Comment: Half a second! Thank you very much!

Comment: I've edited your answer @ShaiRado, to remove the select. Note I haven't tested this but see no reason why it shouldn't work. Simply operating directly on the range without selecting it in between!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work given your scenario, but it's worth a try.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]

The AddIn will allow you to merge files that contain certain names as well as fixed ranges from each file.  Give it a try and see how you get along.

Good luck!

Comment: Problem was solved ages ago. Question was about VBA not about plugins.